# Block sqlmap injection request via Iptalbes/firewall

Tags: block, iptables, sqlmap

I was checking the security on my server RHEL-5. I was running sqlmap and its gone through smoothly via iptables firewall.

I want to block the sqlmap injection via firewall. So If anybody will try the same it sud be block in firewall.

Answer (score 0):

That might not be possible to do.

You could block any attempts to connect that use a user-agent containing the string "sqlmap". However, sqlmap comes with the --random-agent option which would make it appear just like any other browser.

If you are running a web server, it would be very difficult to differentiate between sqlmap and legitimate requests.

What you need is an IDS, or mod_security (if you use apache).